# Как в java организовать перебор и считывание данных из всех полей jTextField

Tags: java

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Информации для ответа конечно слишком мало, но попробую ответить.

1. ***Перебор***. **Путь первый**. Хранить ссылки на все объекты JTextField в какой-нибудь структуре (LinkedList, массив... что угодно), чтобы можно было бы легко и просто обращаться как к отдельному элементу, так и перебирать их в цикле. **Путь второй**. Все JTextField должны лежать в каком-то одном контейнере и, имея ссылку на этот контейнер, вы сможете получить массив всех компонентов, лежащих в этом контейнере методом getComponents(). Однако, если в этом контейнере хранятся не только JTextField, не забудьте проверить полученные компоненты на принадлежность к нужному вам классу и привести их к этому классу.
2. ***Считывание данных***. Да здравствует метод getText().

Разверну ответ, добавив немного кода:
Для примера возьмем такую структуру графических элементов

```
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
for(int p=0; p<9; p++){
  JPanel subPanel = new JPanel();
  for(int s=0; s<9; s++){
    subPanel.add(new JTextField());
  }
  mainPanel.add(subPanel);
}
```

Так можно считать их в массив, но раз вы говорите, о том, что могут появиться новые текстовые поля, то лучше использовать список:

```
LinkedList<String> values = new LinkedList<String>();
for (Component sub : mainPanel.getComponents()) {
  JPanel subPanel = (JPanel)sub;
  Component[] texts = subPanel.getComponents();
  for(Component textField: texts){
    JTextField text = (JTextField)textField;
    values.add(text.getText());
  }
}
```

Естественно, что это только алгоритм. Нужно добавить обработку исключений для приведения типов и многое другое, но идея думаю понятна.

Comment: Спасибо, если можно поподробнее. С моей стороны подробности такие:
есть 9 панелей на каждой по 9 "текстфилдов" нужно читать их в массив в том порядке как они находятся + названия типа pole1, pole2... pole81. Дополнительная сложность в том, что возможно потом необходимо будет добавить на форму еще несколько таких панелей с минимальной заменой кода

Comment: Добавил немного кода... Посмотрите.

Comment: к сожалению не всегда есть возможность в массиве работать с элементами ГУИ. чтоб хоть как-то следовать паттерну MVC, я бы посоветовал делать интерфейс в котором делать геттеры/сеттеры нужных свойств.  

    class MyFrame extends Frame implements Configuration {...}
    class AnotherClass 
    {
    public void someMethod (Configuration c)
    {
    c.setProperty1(c.getProperty1() + 2);
    }
    }
    
    public interface Configuration
    {
    void setProperty1(int value);
    int getProperty1();
    }

Comment: append^^: реализация интерфейса в классе MyFrame "спрячет" view, - работу с элементами ГУИ. Внешний клас будет работать только с моделью, - интерфейсом Configuration.